# I can't run two websocket clients simultanously

Tags: python, websocket, python-asyncio, binance-api-client

When I try to run 2 WebSocket clients only one is working.

```
import asyncio
import re
from binance import AsyncClient, BinanceSocketManager
import websocket
from websocket import create_connection


tokenList=['btcusdt@ticker']


async def binancews():
    client = await AsyncClient.create()
    bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
    # start any sockets here, i.e a trade socket
    # ms = bm.trade_socket('BNBBTC')
    ms = bm.multiplex_socket(tokenList)
    # then start receiving messages
    async with ms as tscm:
        while True:
            res = await tscm.recv()

            print(res)

    await client.close_connection()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(binancews())


ws = websocket.WebSocket()
ws = create_connection("wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=trade:XBTUSD")
ws.send("Hello, Server")
while(1):
    print(ws.recv())
```

So if I uncomment this  # loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
# loop.run_until_complete(main()) lines than  wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime?subscribe=trade:XBTUSD WebSockets won't run but Binance's will.   at separate files, they both run but when they are together I can't make them run together. What should I do?

Comment: Only one is running because that's the logic you have written.  I assume this is your main program module, so the if statement is true.  As your code stands you run main() as an asyncio Task and wait for it to finish - that's what `run_until_complete` does.  So the rest of your code won't be reached until main is done.  If you comment out the two loop statements, of course your main() function will not run but you will create and use the web socket.  So why can't you run both sockets in two different asyncio tasks, if that's the behavior you want?

Comment: I'm new to python. Can you modify the code so that it will run both?

Comment: Well, you connect with Binance using async functions, and with bitmex using sync functions.  That's definitely making your life difficult.

Comment: I think you are right. I'm trying to fix it now with the way you advised.  I'll let you know. I had some success but don't know if it will continue like this :)

Comment: @PaulCornelius I think you saved my life. It's working lol... After I moved away from connection and using connect... More research is needed but thanks! :D

Comment: So problem solved! I used import websockets and not websocket which probably had problem with it or maybe not... Anyways with websockets everything was achieved! And it works with binance's websockets

Comment: Wow, it's not every day that I manage to save a life :-) I'm glad you got it to work.